# How to parse a JSON file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have a JSON file which contains the following:

```
[
  {
    “name”: “Joshia \”Placement\” Fonz”,
    “color”: “white”
  },
  {
    "name": “Trin Brin”,
    “color”: “black”
  },
  {
    “name”: “Su Et”,
    “color”: “yellow”
  }
]
```

And I would like to parse it to use the array and objects for the application. So `'./students.json'` being the path for the JSON file, I attempted `JSON.parse('./students.json')` but got an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 0`, and tried `JSON.stringify('./students.json')` but it simply returned me the exact string of the path `'./students.json'`.

So can I parse the JSON file in Javascript to use the array?

Thank you

Comment: try JSONlint.com to check whether the JSON format is valid or not.

Comment: btw, the quotes look different.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `ajax` request for that, `jQuery` (`$`) provides an abstraction for `XHR`.

```
$.get("./students.json", function(data){
   //success callback
   // data is the json you requested already parsed
}, "json");
```

Is the fastest way to achieve your goal, as long as by default client side is not able to read a file from the server even if there are `file` API for client-side file reading but I guess that in this case it may provide you more problems than it actually solve.

[File](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPobO7v4LQAhXGORoKHXleCc8QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FFile&usg=AFQjCNGDZ5qFMUp-HbsiHY-kEaayf7AnlQ&sig2=EU3udQub_swkvVlqTDqMIQ)

[FileReader](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPobO7v4LQAhXGORoKHXleCc8QFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FFileReader&usg=AFQjCNH3ObAbH156rjNhXJ_v5GfnMXh4zA&sig2=8PYNJ0uiwlJI_J7vA-I3fQ)

Comment: I'm not making any requests. I just have a file called `students.json` and trying to use the array.

Comment: And to retrieve that file you need to make a request. The client side won't magically retrieve it through a path.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are parsing the string './students.json' not what is inside the file. You should open the file and then take the info. You could use this example to read the file https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446538/5334265 . Then use JSON.parse to the content.

Comment: I'm not making any requests. I already have the file called `students.json` and I want to parse it to use the array. How can I do that?

Comment: but you need a request to your own server to get the file. Like the example of @steo

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a leagal javascript so you can just add to your page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./students.json"></script>
```